# How to resolve problem of KeyError 'order_line' in odoo 11

Tags: odoo

I have this error in odoo 11:

```
field = model._fields[fname]
KeyError: 'order_line'
```

I try to write a function to compute numbers of records in module `account.invoice`.

What argument to put in `@api.depends('argument_to_put_here')`?

Comment: Code you provide you function? There is no field `order_line` on model `account.invoice`, so this function can't depend on this field. Maybe you've meant to depend on `invoice_line_ids` which are the invoice lines you want to count?

Comment: yes
field=invoice_line_ids Object account.invoice
how to write this function plaise ?

Comment: You really need to learn that by yourself. There is a nice [beginners tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html) and there are also books out how to develop for Odoo.